# Kernel Update info

Tags: kernel, updates

where I can get information as to why Ubuntu would like to upgrade the kernel, in fact I would like to know if the upgrade corrects a security issue (and which one) or whatever.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the change logs which are available for all upgraded packages (not just the kernel). One source would be the [Ubuntu Security Notices](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/). Another one is the [package directory](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). There you'll find, for example, the [information for linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic). In the sidebar on the right, there's a link to the [changelogs](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-lts-xenial/linux-lts-xenial_4.4.0-45.66~14.04.1/changelog).

But you should be aware that the information in the changelogs is very technical and can contain a lot of jargon. So for more general information, just the Linux media (websites, newsletters etc.) may be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Kernels (updates and patches, might I add) provide fixes and optimizations for a variety of hardware and security issues- as a matter of fact, Kernels are essentially your entire system base- it is what interfaces with your hardware.

For example, newer Kernels provide new and updated support for different network devices, CPUs (such as Kaby Lake CPUs newly tweaked and updated by the 4.8 kernel), etc.

In terms of security, newer Kernels, along with security patches, provide security updates to current threats.